# $ionicPlatform.ready is not firing after platform update ios

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

The problem is that `$ionicPlatform.ready` is not firing after running `ionic platform update ios;` or `cordova platform update ios;`

Here are the steps to replicate:

- enter `ionic start myApp blank` into the terminal
- choose `n` for "create and ionic.io account"
- enter `vi myApp/www/js/app.js`
- add "angular['test_this'] = 123;" after the line "$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {"
- run `ionic build`
- open the app in an iOS device, open that devices console, and notice that angular.test_this is set to 123
- close out of everything
- run `ionic platform update ios`
- run `ionic build`
- open the app in an iOS device, open that devices console, and notice that now that angular.test_this is `undefined`